# Cartesian Coordinates & Layout

Tags: game-design, camera, coordinates, perspective

The way cartesian coordinations are presented and used is kinda confusing.

When working with 2D the vertical axis is Y, though when working with 3D the vertical axis is Z and Y becomes the "depth" axis.

Basically I'm thinking the correct way, and best way would be to use the layout of axis.

[image]

Though Blender (3D modelling program) and other program, a lot games, present the axis in the "weird order" (my opinion)

[image]

Also if you read on Wikipedia about cartesian coordinates, your are presented with that layout of axis.

[Wikipedia Cartesian Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates_in_three_dimensions)

Is there any specific or logical reason for this "flip" of axis?

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'flip' here; both coordinate systems are exactly the same. Instead, the two images have been created using two differently oriented cameras. Which direction is 'up' is not defined by the coordinate system, but by an arbitrary mental note you make.

Comment: "Flipped" is what I say, I mean, is there any reason why when it's 3D, Z becomes the vertical axis and Y the depth (which I think should be flipped), and as I said what I mean about that is because the majority of programs and games you Z as the vertical axis. Where I would say Z is the depth axis.